# Does Backbone need Underscore?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Due to the 
[Backbone.js: `extend` undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875743/backbone-js-extend-undefined)
and my own errors after comment underscore.js :

Does Backbone need Underscore?
Need Partly? (which parts?)

Comment: quoting the (first page of the) docs "Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.4.3)." So yeah, it needs underscore badly

Comment: I almost knew that it did need it but also could not find even though its on the top of the page, but this question I did find and it answered my question. Not sure why the down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Backbone has an explicit dependency on Underscore, it says so right at the top of the Backbone page: http://backbonejs.org/

> Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.4.3).