# Extending the Backbone.js router while using Mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mapbox

For a current project using [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.3.0/) when attempting to extend the backbone router to provide client side URL routing for my site (not navigating routing) I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
```

I think that Mapbox.js is built on backbone and allows to you implement some routing functionality but is there a way to over ride it?

Like Leaflet.js offers similar routing functionality but gives allows you to extend the Backbone router however provides backbone globally. Like in this demo app with leaflet it works fine http://mpmckenna8.github.io/sdparks/#park/McCain_Valley_Nat

But errors abound with Mapbox.js as in: http://mpmckenna8.github.io/ccsfmapapp/site/

Comment: The error states that backbone is not available when the code runs. You just need to add it. If that doesn't help, you should provide the code or a [mcve]

Comment: Actually the problem was that I needed to load underscore.js before backbone.js.as was basically answered in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875743/backbone-js-extend-undefined?rq=1